# How to print out the rank number of a word?

Tags: python

I have the code for ranking the number of words in a txt file which I imported from a url.

```
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter

N = 20
words = {}

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in open("output.txt")
                                     for word in line.split())

for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]


for word, frequency in top_words:
  print("%s %d" % (word, frequency))
```

So from the text file, it would return:

```
hello 8
him 5
your 4
```

The code does the ranking, but is there a way to print out the ranking number?

I would want it to look like this.

```
hello 1 8
him 2 5
your 3 4
```

The first number is the overall rank and the second number is the frequency of the word in that text file. I tried doing like counting the rank.

```
rank=0
if top_words:
  rank+=1
```

But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, (word, frequency) in enumerate(top_words, start=1):
    print("%s %d %d" % (word, i, frequency))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rank = 0    

for word, frequency in top_words:
  rank += 1
  print("%s %d %d" % (word,rank, frequency))
```

That should work.